# Read int and string with a delimeter from a file in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read line by line in a file. Basically each line will have the Id number, price, qty and the name of the book. I know that after each input, I have to put the delimiter flag there to stop the reading, but I don't know how. I was trying to use `getline()`, yet, `getline()` can only take in a string, and that is not the case for the id #, the price and the qty. Would anyone care to show me the way how to read the file ? Thank you, and this is what I have so far.

Example:
The file should contain many line, each line will have a format like this:
- The first number is the id number
- The second one is the price
- Third one is the qty
- The last one is the title of the book

123,19.99,5,summer is fun

```
void ReadFromFile(int ids[], int prices[], int qty[], string titles[], int& count)
{
    ifstream infile("tomatoes.txt");
    if(!infile.is_open())
        cout << "File does not exists" << endl;
    else
    {
        while(!infile.eof())
        {
            infile >> ids[count];
            infile >> prices[count];
            infile >> qty[count];
            getline(infile, titles[count]);
            if(!infile.eof())
                count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And yet, another file parsing question.  Search Stackoverflow for "c++ read file parse" for more like this one.

Comment: I've been searching and asked around, and yet, no one seems to give me the right answer yet :(

Comment: So I take it you can't look at other similar examples and compare yours to theirs.  I was just answer one earlier today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here we go again, another parsing issue.

**The fundamental read loop.**
Reading a file does not use the `eof` method to determine end of file.  You can search StackOverflow for "c++ read eof while" for some examples.

```
std::string textline;
while (getline(infile, textline)
{
}
```

The above loop will read one text line at a time until it fails reading one, which is usually the end of the file.

**Parsing the text**
We can parse the text string by treating it as an input stream.  This involves using `std::istringstream`, and `getline`.
There is an *overloaded* version of `getline` that will read text until a specified *delimiter* is found.  In your case, this *delimiter* is a comma.

```
std::string textline;
while (getline(infile, textline)
{
   string comma_string;
   std::istringstream text_stream(textline);
   text_stream >> id;
   getline(text_stream, comma_string, ','); // Read characters after number until comma.
   text_stream >> price;
   getline(text_stream, comma_string, ','); // Read characters after number until comma.
   text_stream >> quantity;
   getline(text_stream, comma_string, ','); // Read characters after number until comma.
   // Read the remaining text, until end of line, as the title.
   getline(text_stream, title, '\n');
}
```

**Storing the record**
The input loop has been expanded to read in the fields.  They should be stored in an object.

```
std::string textline;
while (getline(infile, textline)
{
   string comma_string;
   std::istringstream text_stream(textline);
   text_stream >> id;
   getline(text_stream, comma_string, ','); // Read characters after number until comma.
   text_stream >> price;
   getline(text_stream, comma_string, ','); // Read characters after number until comma.
   text_stream >> quantity;
   getline(text_stream, comma_string, ','); // Read characters after number until comma.

   // Read the remaining text, until end of line, as the title.
   getline(text_stream, title, '\n');

   // Put the file data fields into an object.
   book.id = id;
   book.price = price;
   book.quantity = quantity;
   book.title = title;
}
```

**Append data to container**

```
std::string textline;
std::vector<Book> catalog;
while (getline(infile, textline)
{
   string comma_string;
   std::istringstream text_stream(textline);
   text_stream >> id;
   getline(text_stream, comma_string, ','); // Read characters after number until comma.
   text_stream >> price;
   getline(text_stream, comma_string, ','); // Read characters after number until comma.
   text_stream >> quantity;
   getline(text_stream, comma_string, ','); // Read characters after number until comma.

   // Read the remaining text, until end of line, as the title.
   getline(text_stream, title, '\n');

   // Put the file data fields into an object.
   book.id = id;
   book.price = price;
   book.quantity = quantity;
   book.title = title;

   // Append the book to the catalog
   catalog.push_back(book);
}
```

**Conclusion**
You should not expect people to give you exactly what you want, but you should be able to take code fragments and compare them to yours and see if you can make them work.

Comment: thanks for taking time to explain things so clearly. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole line and then use `sscanf()` to extract the values:

```
string line;
getline(infile, line);

int id, quantity;
double price;
char title[20];

sscanf(line.c_str(), "%d,%lf,%d,%[^\n]", &id, &price, &quantity, title);

cout << "id = " << id << endl;
cout << "price = " << price << endl;
cout << "quantity = " << quantity << endl;
cout << "title = " << title << endl;
```

A little dirty but it works. BTW: `%[^\n]` reads all characters till the end of the line.

Comment: If you are using `std::string`, shouldn't you use `std::istringstream` instead of `sscanf`?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Sure, it would be better to be consistent and not to mix C and C++. It was only the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overloaded version of get that allows you to specify a delimiter.

One way to solve this is to:

```
for(int count = 0; infile.eof() == false; count++ )
{
   // for the line
   stringstream currentLine;

   // get a line at a time
   infile.get(currentLine)

   // for the element
   stringstream currentElement;

   // work on that line
   currentLine.get(currentElement,',');
   currentElement >> ids[count];
   currentElement.str();

   currentLine.get(currentElement,',');
   currentElement >> prices[count];
   currentElement.str();

   // etc...

}
```

Comment: infile.get(*(currentLine.rdbuf()))

Comment: still got error on this line: currentLine.get(currentElement,',');

Comment: same change there too: 

currentLine.get(*(currentElement.rdbuf()),',');